# javascript canvas setTimeout console TypeError: is not a function

Tags: javascript, canvas, settimeout

I'm trying to execute a function 'draw' when a button is clicked (button id is also draw). When clicking the button the function runs successfully, however the repeated iterations do not run. I've therefore narrowed the issue to the setTimeout. I get the following message "draw is not a function". This is confusing because it definitely IS a function. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
 var draw1 = document.getElementById('draw');
 draw1.addEventListener('click',draw);

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;

function draw(aaa,bbb){
      ctx.save();//save the cavas state if required
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,100,100)//clear canvas for redrawing
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,200,0,1)';//style a green box
      ctx.fillRect (x, 20, 50, 50);//draw the rectangle
      ctx.restore();//restore the canvas state if saved
      x += 5;//increment the x position by some numeric value
      console.log(x);
      console.log(y);
      var loopTimer = setTimeout('draw(' + x +','+ 0 +')',200);
    }
```

Comment: move the definition of draw before actually binding it..

Comment: `draw1.addEventListener('click',draw);` before this line

Comment: @Minato: There's no need, function declarations are hoisted.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Its always a good programming practice to declare them before using them :P

Comment: @Minato: No, it's always good programming practice to know how things work. Referring to functions declared later in the code is completely normal and standard practice in JavaScript (and many other languages).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I always did declare(defined them later in c/cpp) them before using them so I follow the same convention in JS and all other languages I program into :P.. Thanks for the bit of knowledge :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use strings for function call. It is a really bad practice.

Change it to an anonymous function:

```
var loopTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    draw(x, 0);
}, 200);
```

As long as your `x` and `y` are global and you don't use arguments, you can remove them from your `draw` method and call it even simpler, without closures:

```
function draw(){
    ctx.save();//save the cavas state if required
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,100,100)//clear canvas for redrawing
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,200,0,1)';//style a green box
    ctx.fillRect (x, 20, 50, 50);//draw the rectangle
    ctx.restore();//restore the canvas state if saved
    x += 5;//increment the x position by some numeric value
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
    var loopTimer = setTimeout(draw, 200);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the explanation and advice. Definitely looks a lot more logical this way. Much appreciated.

Comment: With your (good) suggestion to use the function, not a string, there's **no** reason to make `x` and `y` globals. `draw` doesn't have to be global anymore either.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `x` and `y` are globals in the OP's original code. He isn't using `aaa` and `bbb` arguments. At the same time, I agree that it is better to use arguments :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: I didn't say you had to use arguments, just that they don't need to be *globals*. (I do think using arguments is frequently best, but it's also fine for `draw` just to close over what it needs in a non-global context.) Also, I suspect that `x` and `y` *aren't* globals in the OP's code, given the error. I think the whole thing is inside a function, which is why `draw` isn't a global, and why the OP is getting the error. If the code were as shown at global scope, the string with `setTimeout` would work.